# Can Docker Image compilation have side effects?

Tags: security, docker, compilation, side-effects

Is it safe to build Docker Images based on untrusted code on my server?

I know that running the resulting Images is safe (in so far as something this complicated can ever be truly safe), but can building them have side effects?

Comment: What do you mean untrusted code on your server? You should trust the base image you're using, that's why the official images (Prefixed with _) are best to use, or find the Dockerfile of the hosted image and build it yourself to ensure you know what's going into it.

Comment: I use Docker to isolate and run untrusted code provided by users.